# Magento categories display in front end question

Tags: magento

```
+Parent cat1
+Parent cat2
+Parent cat3
   +subcat1
      -subcat11
      -subcat12
   subcat2  
   subcat3
+Parent cat4
```

My requirement is when you click the parent `cat3` how can I display the `subcat1` and `subact2`?
When I click the `subcat11` I cannot display the `subcat2`, `subcat3`.

What I require is when I click the `subcat11` or `subcat12` it should show like this below

```
  subcat1
      -subcat11
      -subcat12
   subcat2  
   subcat3
```

Can you help me with this?
My code is given below.

```
$loadCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCat->getParentId());
$subCategories = explode(',', $loadCategory->getChildren()); 

foreach ( $subCategories as $subCategoryId )
{   
    $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCategoryId);

    if ($cat->getIsActive())
    {         
        if ($currentCat->getEntityId() == $subCategoryId)
        {
            echo '<li ><a href="'.$cat->getURL().'">'.$cat->getName().'</a></li>'; 
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [vertical navigation extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/763/vertical-navigation-with-css-classes) has a flexible option to choose which categories will appear as 'root'. Perhaps you can use this instead of writing it yourself.